# Allow users registered on Wordpress to log in without having confirmed activation via the link sent by email to the user

Tags: php, wordpress

Good Evening.

I Have a little problem with Wordpress.

I have 400 users registered via from on Wordpress who must log in to view a live broadcast on my site. When they try to login, activation is requested via a link received on their email. Is it possible to disable this limit and allow users to log in anyway?

Maybe exist a Plugin or a filter.

Thanks

Comment: The behaviour you are suggesting here is not something that comes out of the box with wordpress. You need to tell us from where is this activation being sent. Is there a snippet you added or plugin that you installed. Without that one cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity forms with user registration addon will work.

It will give you 2 options,

1. Direct activation
2. Manual activation by admin

Even the account credentials will be shared with user so that they can directly login

https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/add-ons-gravity-forms/user-registration-add-on/?_ga=2.171967459.1182521698.1624386158-484023262.1624386158